# Get URL parameters from ring

Tags: clojure, ring

Starting with string `"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0"`, I'd like to get `{:v P76Vbsk_3J0}`.

I am nearly there with:

```
(#'ring.middleware.params/parse-params "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0" "UTF-8")
=> {"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v" "P76Vbsk_3J0"}

(clojure.walk/keywordize-keys {"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v" "P76Vbsk_3J0"})
=> {:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v "P76Vbsk_3J0"}
```

Is there something I can grab from `ring` to get me the rest of the way there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ring.middleware.params/parse-params` expects only to receive a query parameter string so you need to remove everything before and including the `?`, something like this will work:

```
(#'ring.middleware.params/parse-params
  (second (.split "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0" "\\?"))
  "UTF-8")
;=> {"v" "P76Vbsk_3J0"}
```

Note that you are using a function that is not a part of the public API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do but the idiomatic ring way to do that is using `ring.middleware.params/wrap-params` and `ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params`. Then the request map will contain a `:param` key with what you want.

Comment: I'm not starting with a request. I'm starting with a `GET` URL string and using the `ring` library to get the `GET parameters`. Alternatively, I'm not understanding what you're saying; can you post a code example?

Comment: If you are not starting with a request my code wouldn't help. I was just pointing that if you were using requests there is an easy way to do what you want. Sorry about that.